# How to make elements inside a <div> tag disappear one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate, vertical-scrolling

I need to implement a vertical scroller and I decided to do that as a list of child  elements nested inside a parent  and hide/remove/slideUp those  one at a time, causing the effect of the elements below it moving up.

I'm trying to do that using JQuery's .each() for iterating over the nested , removing the current one, waiting a bit, and moving to the next one.

I wrote the code below as an attempt to do that. It waits a few seconds and removes all the elements at once, negating the effect I intended to have.

I searched around and all other answers I found around here are about having a delay before acting over all the elements. I can do that already, but what should I do to make the child  disappear one at a time?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#scroller").find("div").each(function() {
    console.log(this);
    $(this).delay(10000).slideUp();
    //        $(this).slideUp();
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="scroller" id="scroller">
  <div id="1">texto 1</div>
  <div id="2">texto 2</div>
  <div id="3">texto 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason they're disappearing all at once is because the .delay function does not pause your code, it simply schedules the functions to run at an offset time in the future. What your code is doing is scheduling `.slideUp()` to run at 10000 ms in the future for each div all in one go.

What you can do instead of offset each delay by the amount of time you want between elements disappearing. I've set the default delay to be 5000 ms so you can quickly see its effect.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#scroller").find("div").each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay( (1 + index) * 5000 ).slideUp();
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="scroller" id="scroller">
  <div id="1">texto 1</div>
  <div id="2">texto 2</div>
  <div id="3">texto 3</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rew37s2m/) (hit Run at the top to see it again).

Comment: Worked great, thanks. It's even better using the index, instead of the offset, as @dark4p did. I changed your answer with that improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#scroller").find("div").each(function (index) {
        var el = $(this);

        setTimeout(function (){ 
          el.slideUp();
        },1000 * index);
      });

 });
```

Comment: This one worked, but @analytalica's sollution looks cleaner, and it even has a JSFiddle. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the setTimeout method to time each of the disappearances.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#1").slideUp();
}, 1000);
// ...
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain they will all still run at the same time. setTimeout does not wait before calling a function, it schedules it ahead of time.

Comment: I tried using setTimeout too, before creating the question (after all, it's a common suggestion here) and, yes, all the elements disappeared at the same time. :-/